# Problema no logout com Google login social

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tendo problema para executar o logout com o Google login social.
Consegui definir o login e executo com sucesso recebendo o retorno do nome, email e foto, e redireciono para o dashboard com sucesso.

No dashboard eu inseri as configurações de meta, o plataform.js e o link para sair da página, e recebo a seguinte mensagem,

TypeError: gapi.auth2 is undefined

```
<a onclick="signOut();"> sair</a>

function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            alert('OK');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar recarregar e iniciar a lib `gapi.auth2` na página do dashboard. Exemplo (substitua `SEU_ID_DE_CLIENTE` pelo seu `id` atual):

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="SEU_ID_DE_CLIENTE">
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function () {
         alert('OK');
      });
    }

    function onLoad() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init();
      });
    }
  </script>
  <a onclick="signOut();"> sair</a>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Resolveu dvd.. valeu!!